# Java XML RPC date iso 8601 with timezone

Tags: java, date, format, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I am having a hard time trying to make a web service client work.  It is a XML RPC specification.  I am using Apache WS XML-RPC library, which I find full of holes that causes problem due to Serialization.  I have to send a Date  parameter for the library to add the tags , however the web service expects it with the TZ, that means adding -0500 at the end of the Date object.  If I dont send it as Date Object, it wont add the  tags and it will fail.  And when trying to do this:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    String fecha = df.format(new Date());
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(fecha);
```

And using parameter date, and it always sends it as

```
    <dateTime.iso8601>20130517T20:30:33</dateTime.iso8601>
```

Can't find a way for it to send it as Date object in the format above but with the -0500 at the end.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this case? we are also looking for Date object in above format.

Comment: See solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763272/how-to-get-apache-xml-rpc-3-1-3-compliance-iso-date-format-along-with-time-zone/23996098#23996098

Comment: I am sorry for late answer, it did worked for me that time... just needed to modify the set type factory.